# Mapping a Subdomain to a NodeJS web server running in a docker container with a specific port?

Tags: node.js, docker, http, nginx, webserver

I have a server running Pterodactyl panel which uses Docker. I'm using a Nodemon js egg to run a Node JS webserver I developed. The server uses 5500 as the port. The ufw firewall is set up correctly.

An issue I am having is accessing the webserver from a subdomain. I can access the webserver using [server ip]:5500 perfectly fine. I set up an A record pointing the subdomain to the server IP but it brings me to the Pterodactyl panel instead of the webserver.

I have edited the Nginx (pterodactyl.conf) config to point it to the correct port but it doesn't seem to work still.

What would I need to do to make it work?

[Screenshot of Nginx Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYsYS.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the new website is not currently listening to that port. It also happened to me, all sub domains were pointing to pterodactyl panel, it was because the new website was not listening to new port, than you need to restart nginx so it shows correctly